# How do I create a sliding window using a for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sliding-window

I have neural data collected across 16 different channels. This data was recorded over a 30 second period.

Over a 10s period (from 20 - 30s), I want to record the number of neural data points that are greater than or equal to a specified threshold. I would like to do this according to bins of 0.001s.

I am using MATLAB 2019b.

My code so far looks like this:

```
t1 = 20;
t2 = 30;

ind1 = find(tim_trl>=t1, 1);
ind2 = find(tim_trl>=t2, 1);

time1 = tim_trl(ind1:ind2); %10s window

sampRate = 24414; %sampling freq (Hz), samples per sec
muaWindow = 0.001; %1ms window

binWidth = round(muaWindow*sampRate); %samples per 1ms window
threshold = 0.018;
    
    for jj = 1:16 %ch
        
        data = AbData(ind1:ind2, jj); %10 sec of data
   
        for kk = 1:10000 
            
            abDataBin = data(1:binWidth,jj); %data in 1 bin
            dataThreshold = find(abDataBin >= threshold); %find data points >= threshold
            mua(kk,jj) = sum(dataThreshold); %number of data pts over threshold per ch
           
        end
        
    end
```

So far, I'm just having a bit of trouble at this point:

```
abDataBin = data(1:binWidth,jj); %data in 1 bin
```

When I run the loop, the data in bin 1 gets overwritten, rather than shift to bin 2, 3...10000. I'd appreciate any feedback on fixing this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To get help, please include a minimal example with code that can be run (define all variables), and define what the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use the running variable as index to access your data. Try

```
% create data with 16 channels
AbData = rand(10000,16);

binWidth = 24;
threshold = 0.001;

for channel=1:16
    
    data = AbData(2001:3000,channel);   
    counter = 1;  % needed for mua indexing

    % looping over the bin starting indeces
    for window=1:binWidth:length(data)-(binWidth)
        % access data in one bin
        bindata = data(window:window+binWidth);
        % calculate ms above threshold
        mua(counter, channel) = sum(bindata >= threshold);
         
        counter = counter+1;  
    end
end
```

EDIT:
your `data` variable is of dimension nx1, therefore doenst need the column indexing with `jj`

Comment: Thanks, Ive already tried that, but I get the error msg: Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).

Comment: I essentially would like my data to shift every 24 samples or 1 bin (i.e. 1:24, 25:48, 48:72....9976:10000) and sum the number of data elements per bin that are >=threshold. That's what I'm trying to do, but I am having trouble doing it.

Comment: Thanks for this! I really appreciate it. It does what I want it to do, except I end up with an mua matrix of 10172 x 16, when it should be 10000 (or 10001 because of the sum row) x 16 when I run the code on my data. I am looking at bins that are 0.001s (which essentially are 24 data elements), and given that I'm focusing on 10s I should end up with a 10000 x 16 matrix. The data matrix that I have (which is 10s long) is 244141 x 16.

Comment: So 24 elements are 1 ms?

Comment: My sampling rate is 24414 Hz and I'm calculating mua according to a 0.001s window, so technically there are 24.414 elements per 0.001s, but I had to round that number resulting in 24 elements per 0.001s. For my data, I am treating 24 elements as 1ms.

Comment: Then you only need to adjust the indeces in `data = AbData(2001:3000,channel);`. I assumed that one bin is one ms. but in your case one bin is 1/24ms.
So if your total is 30sec with 30*1000*24 entries, then your indeces for 10 to 20 secs is  `data = AbData(10*1000*24:20*1000*24,channel);`

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help!